# jquery next() outside of div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use next() to toggle a div. The problem is that the "trigger" is in a different div than the one I want to toggle. An example that works:

```
$("span.trigger").click(function(){
        $(this).next("div.task_description").slideToggle("fast");
});

<span class="trigger">The trigger</span>
<div class="task_description ">
  some content
</div>
```

But the way I need the html setup is:

```
<div>
  <span class="trigger">The trigger</span>
</div>
<div class="task_description ">
  some content
</div>
```

That doesn't work... any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you need a `.parent()` as well, like this:

```
$("span.trigger").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().next("div.task_description").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Alternatively, if your nesting may change, you can go up to the `<div>` you're in, like this:

```
$(this).closest("div").next("div.task_description").slideToggle("fast");
```

Comment: I actually have div's in-between the trigger and the toggling div... used nextAll() and everything is perfect.. Thanks!

Comment: @mike - make sure to use `.nextAll(".task_description:first")` if you just want the first one of that class that follows!